# Share same pagination code for different views in Django

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-views

I'm building a simple blog app using Django.
This app has a main template `blog.html` which is shared between the following views:

- **blog** (url: `/blog/[page number]`) 
  Main page of the blog, displays the last articles
- **search** (url: `/search/<query>/[page number]`) 
  Will display the articles who match the query
- **category** (url: `/category/<category name>/[page number]`) 
  Will display the articles from the given category

Each a this views provides the template `blog.html` with an object `page` obtained using the function `Paginator` each time with a different objects list (depending on the view).

Here is my problem: 
The template `blog.html` contains a pager

```
<ul class="pager">
    {% if page.has_previous %}
        <li class="previous">
            <a href="{{ url_previous_page }}" class="btn btn-primary" >&larr; Older</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page.has_next %}
        <li class="next">
            <a href="{{ url_next_page }}" class="btn btn-primary" >Newer &rarr;</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

How can I define in an elegant way the values of `url_next_page` and `url_previous_page` in all the views?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really need to supply the links for the next and previous buttons like that. I would suggest changing your pagination code to be something like this:

```
<div class="pagination-wrap">
    <span class="pagination-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="pagination-nav previous"></a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="current">
            {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="pagination-nav next"></a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
    <div>{{ page_obj.start_index }} to {{ page_obj.end_index }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.count }}</div>
</div>
```

In your views, all you need to specify is the number of objects to paginate by with `paginate_by = 15`.

If you really want to, you could create a mixin for your list views to use which has a method that could return the url you want.

Comment: Thank you. the problem is that the page is not specified as query parameter but as part of the url (example: /category/mycategory/3 )